# Removing python path hardcode and passing list

Tags: python, python-requests, os.walk, pathlib

**Update 1/8/2019 0945 EST

I have passed the script through the function given by bhakta0007 but received a path error "The system cannot find the path specified:".

After review, I added the below statement to the end of the script to pass the list through the function and the code works.

for f in fList:
    excel_csv(fList)

I have added an answer to the question below.

I have a small script that I run to convert excel files to .csv. Currently , I have to repeat the script with the paths hardcoded in. The current paths have the exact same structure with the exceptions of a 3 digit identifier which I would like to create a list that I can call from.  Below is my code. You will see I have variables that have the paths and I pass these variables where needed.I have looked into os.path, glob, and pathlib, but I can't find a good solution for the problem.

**Original Code**

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil


Target_Path     =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/261/Edlog/Working/'))
Move_Path       =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/261/Edlog/ToProcess/'))
Process_Path    =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/261/Edlog/Processed/'))
os.chdir(Target_Path)

try:
    for f in glob.glob('*.xls'):
        out = f.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
        df = pd.read_excel(f,)
        df.to_csv(out, index=False)

finally:
    for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
        out = f.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
        df = pd.read_excel(f,)
        df.to_csv(out, index=False)

xlsCounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.xls"))
xlsxCounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.xlsx"))
csvcounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.csv"))

if csvcounter == xlsCounter + xlsxCounter :
    print('Complete Convert')

else: 
    print('Failed Convert')   

for files in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    shutil.move(files, Move_Path)

for files in glob.glob('*.xls'):
    shutil.move(files, Process_Path)

for files in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    shutil.move(files, Process_Path)



if len(os.listdir(Target_Path) ) == 0:
    print('Complete Move')

else: 
    print('Failed Move')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil

def process(folders):
    for f in folders:
        Target_Path     =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/{}/Edlog/Working/').format(folder))
        Move_Path       =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/{}/Edlog/ToProcess/').format(folder))
        Process_Path    =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname('//fs/Unprocessed/{}/Edlog/Processed/').format(folder))
        os.chdir(Target_Path)

        <Rest of our code>

fList = [261, 262, 278, 300]
process(fList)
```

Comment: Thank you, I implemented this change, but I am receiving the error "The system cannot find the path specified: '//fs/Unprocessed/[776]/Edlog/Working'". If I use the same code out of the function and pass a (folder) in the format, or use an Fstring, it is able to find the path.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function created from Bhakta0007, but received "The system cannot find the path specified:" error.

-Revisions added-

I added in a "For" clause at the end of the script and passed the list through the function and was able to run the script successfully in all directories.

I also used an fstring for the "Facility" instead of .format(facility)

**Below is the working Code**

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import shutil

def excel_csv(facility):
    for f in facility:
        Target_Path     =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f'//fs/Unprocessed/{facility}/Edlog/Working/'))
        Move_Path       =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f'//fs/Unprocessed/{facility}/Edlog/ToProcess/'))
        Process_Path    =   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(f'//fs/Unprocessed/{facility}/Edlog/Processed/'))
        os.chdir(Target_Path)

    try:
        for f in glob.glob('*.xls'):
            out = f.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
            df = pd.read_excel(f,)
            df.to_csv(out, index=False)

    finally:
        for f in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
            out = f.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
            df = pd.read_excel(f,)
            df.to_csv(out, index=False)

    xlsCounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.xls"))
    xlsxCounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.xlsx"))
    csvcounter = len(glob.glob1(Target_Path,"*.csv"))

    if csvcounter == xlsCounter + xlsxCounter :
        print('Complete Convert')

    else: 
        print('Failed Convert')   

    for files in glob.glob('*.csv'):
        shutil.move(files, Move_Path)

    for files in glob.glob('*.xls'):
        shutil.move(files, Process_Path)

    for files in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
        shutil.move(files, Process_Path)



    if len(os.listdir(Target_Path) ) == 0:
        print('Complete Move')

    else: 
        print('Failed Move')

fList = ['261', '262', '278', '300']
for f in fList:
    excel_csv(fList)
```